# How do I deactivate Bootstrap-wysihtml5 jquery editor instance?

Tags: wysihtml5

I'm using the Bootstrap-wysihtml5 jquery plugin (https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/) to convert textareas to WYSIWYG. I would like to be able to activate and deactivate the editor by clicking on 2 buttons, so far i can show the editor, please will you let me know how i can deactivate the editor and leave just the textarea and its value. My code is as follows:-

HTML

```
<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="Show Editor"> 
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Hide Editor">
```

Script

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
$('textarea').wysihtml5();
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
// this is where i'm stuck
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to disable/hide the toolbar and editor and had luck with the following commands (to disable the editor). I'm using version wysihtml5-0.3.0_rc2.js)

```
$('#editorId').data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.disable();
$('#editorId').data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.enable();
```

or (to hide the editor)

```
$('#editorId').data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.hide();
$('#editorId').data('wysihtml5').editor.composer.show();
```

To do the same to the toolbar you do the following to hide/show (can't find a wat to disable the toolbar):

```
$('#editorId').data('wysihtml5').editor.toolbar.hide();
$('#editorId').data('wysihtml5').editor.toolbar.show();
```

Comment: Hey Pedro, can you throw some light on how to completely remove the editor? What I am trying to do is, use it as inline editor. Suppose I have two paragraphs, shift+click on the first paragraph turns on the editor on the first paragraph only. Now if the user shift+click on the second paragarph, I want to totally remove the editor on the first paragraph and turn it on for the second paragraph only. I don't know if I am able to communicate well but still you will get the idea. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

A few lines of custom JS code. I think they can help you.

```
var content = $('#content');
var contentPar = content.parent()
contentPar.find('.wysihtml5-toolbar').remove()
contentPar.find('iframe').remove()
contentPar.find('input[name*="wysihtml5"]').remove()
content.show()
```

Comment: Please explain changes and why they are helpful.

Comment: by this you can remove editor from your textarea. '#content' is selector to get your textarea. Prev post didn't help me, because it just hide, but not disable  wysihtml5, i was able to save bold etc.. by ctrl+b.