# How to delete all instance of wysihtml5 editor

Tags: text-editor, rich-text-editor, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5, django-wysihtml5

I have an editor input for adding resume.When user click edit button the editor is loaded via ajax.Here is the code for loading editor:-

```
    jQuery('#resumeEditor').wysihtml5();
```

When the user clicks the cancel button and again tries to edit the resume, multiple editor toolbar appears.
I think I have to delete all instance of editor.But I dont know how!

Any help appreciated.....

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719295/2065594

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Try it out:

```
    $('.wysihtml5-sandbox, .wysihtml5-toolbar').remove();
    $('#resumeEditor').show();
```

It removes the wysihtml5 and shows the textarea as it was before initializing.

Answer (score 0):

I had à similar problem and resolved with this code

```
  $("textarea").next().next().remove();
  $("textarea").prev().remove();
  $("textarea").css('display', 'block');
```

removing the HTML tags by hand, I tried to find some kind of function to remove and have not had succeed